# KendoUI MVVM validation using Datasource Model validation rules

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-mvvm, kendo-validator

Just a little hack for validating against a `kendo.data.Model`

So instead of adding the HTML5 required attribute to each input field manually
this little hack gets all the validation rules that you defined in your Model and
add them as attributes to the appropriate field.  Not fully tested just a quick hack.  According to Kendo the validation rules don't get processed if you are using MVVM, but they do if for example you bind the Dataource directly to a grid.

Code:
I just put this code in a file called `definevalidation.js`

```
function getValidationAttributesFromModel(myFields) {
    var myValidatedFields = [];
    var obj = null;
    $.each(myFields, function(fieldName) {
        if (this.validation) {
            var obj = {
                fieldName : fieldName,
                validation : this.validation
            };
            myValidatedFields.push(obj);
        }
    });

    addValidationAttributes(myValidatedFields);
}

function addValidationAttributes(myValidatedFields) {
    $.each(myValidatedFields, function(index) {
        $('#' + this.fieldName).attr(this.validation);
    });
}
```

Usage:
If ParentDS is your datasource then in your form code just use

```
getValidationAttributesFromModel(ParentDS.options.schema.model.fields)
```

Sample Model:

```
mydatamodel = kendo.data.Model.define({
            id : "__KEY",
            fields : {
                __KEY : {
                    type : "string"
                },
                __STAMP : {
                    type : "number"
                },
                ID : {
                    editable : false,
                    nullable : true
                },
                firstName : {
                    type : "string",
                    validation : {
                        required : true
                    }
                },
                middleName : {
                    type : "string"
                },
                lastName : {
                    type : "string"
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Technically this should be closed as "not a question", but thank you for sharing your solution!

Comment: I'm not really sure but I think there is some sort of wiki section for articles like this... but I could be wrong. Otherwise, you can tick a box that says "Answer your own question" when you're creating a question.